# How to disable HyperThreading on Mac OS X Yosemite?

Tags: macos, cpu

I read that on previous versions of OS X it was possible via hwprefs but I didn't figure out how to use it on 10.10.* (looks like it was removed).
I need to disable HyperThreading for Wineskin.

Comment: May I know why you need to disable it ? (or why Wineskin needs to disable it). Also which mac do you have ?

Comment: Some programs don't work properly with HyperThreading [link](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=32478). Wineskin has a one check box in settings: "Limit to 1 CPU core (set at an OS level for all apps. Only work if you have hwprefs installed)" I have MacBook Pro (Retina, 13, Late 2012) Core i5, Intel HD 4000

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Indeed there is a solution, but you have to have Xcode installed.

Search for "Instruments" with Spotlight (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>), open the application and go to the preferences (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>). Select the "CPUs" tab and untick "Hardware Multi-Threading".

However, after restarting your Mac it will be enabled again.

Comment: Not only after restart but sleep as well.